# reading multiple lines from a file using getline?

Tags: c++, while-loop, fstream, getline

I am trying to read in the data in a names.txt file and output the full name and ideal body weight for each person.  Using a loop to read the names and feet and inches of each person from the file. 
The file reads:

`Tom Atto
6
3
Eaton Wright
5
5
Cary Oki
5
11
Omar Ahmed
5
9`

I'm using the following code for this:

```
string name;
int feet, extraInches, idealWeight;
ifstream inFile;

inFile.open ("names.txt");

while (getline(inFile,name))
{
    inFile >> feet;
    inFile >> extraInches;

    idealWeight = 110 + ((feet - 5) * 12 + extraInches) * 5;

    cout << "The ideal weight for " << name << " is " << idealWeight << "\n";

}
inFile.close();
```

when i run this im getting output:

`The ideal weight for Tom Atto
 is 185
The ideal weight for 
 is -175`

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: why am i getting wrong output

Answer (score 1):

Add this statement in while loop after reading the two extraInches value.

```
inFile.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

It ignores the `'\n'` after the second integer you read in `while` loop. You may refer: [Use getline and >> when read file C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039323/use-getline-and-when-read-file-c)

Answer (score 0):

You are running into problems because after the line

```
inFile >> extraInches;
```

is executed in the first iteration of the loop, there is still a newline character in the stream. The next call to `getline` simply returns an empty line. The subsequent call

```
inFile >> feet;
```

fails but you don't check whether the call was successful.

Couple of things I want to mention in relation to your problem.

1. Mixing unformatted input, using `getline`, and formatted input, using `operator>>` is fraught with problems. Avoid it.
2. To diagnose IO related problems, always check the state of the stream after an operation.

In your case, you can use `getline` to read lines of text, and then use `istringstream` to extract numbers from the lines.

```
while (getline(inFile,name))
{
   std::string line;

   // Read a line of text to extract the feet
   if ( !(inFile >> line ) )
   {
      // Problem
      break;
   }
   else
   {
      std::istringstream str(line);
      if ( !(str >> feet) )
      {
         // Problem
         break;
      }
   }

   // Read a line of text to extract the inches
   if ( !(inFile >> line ) )
   {
      // Problem
      break;
   }
   else
   {
      std::istringstream str(line);
      if ( !(str >> inches) )
      {
         // Problem
         break;
      }
   }

    idealWeight = 110 + ((feet - 5) * 12 + extraInches) * 5;

    cout << "The ideal weight for " << name << " is " << idealWeight << "\n";

}
```